# Scroll bar in Hosted Apps

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a packaged app for Chrome. It's launch page would access data from localStorage and output as HTML.
But my problem is that the app launches in a separate window (shell/panel) with no scroll bars. How can I bring back the scroll bar or launch it as a tab? 
I'm aware of the `"launch": {
      "local_path": "app.html"
    }` trick, but it is depreciation. I'm using `"background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an appropriate `overflow` style for `html` in your CSS:

```
html {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

(you might want to use only `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` depending on your needs)

Comment: Thanks @SondreB for suggesting a change (that was incorrectly rejected by moderators, but was correct). Unfortunately I cannot revert the rejection, but I've fixed my response based on your suggestion.